# HTML id tag conflict with array member

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page has a bunch of id's on `<div>` elements - `xx1, xx2, xx3, xx4`.

I also have an array, `idIndex = [xx1, xx2, xx3, xx4]`, which is used to construct an id tag using jQuery, as follows:

`$("#" + idIndex[2]).text("New text here");`

Unfortunately, this does not work. Javascript dereference the actual ID in the page instead of constructing a tag, and tells me that `idIndex[2]` is actually `[object HTMLDivElement]`, so that the jquery command does not work.

How do I build up the name of the id tag?

Comment: `[object HTMLDivElement]` *is* your DIV tag. It's working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a div with an ID of `xx1`, then there is a global variable called `xx1` which is the element in question.

When you write `idIndex = [xx1]`, you're building up an array of DIV elements. If you want to build up an array of *string* IDs, you need `idIndex = ["xx1"]` etc. The quotes are important.

That said, you *already have* an array of elements. Instead of re-selecting the element from the DOM by their ID, just wrap the element itself in a jQuery object:

```
var $el = $(idIndex[2]);
```

By way of explanation, here's a single div with ID of `xx1`. You can see there is a `xx1` variable and that wrapping it in `$()` works fine:

```js
console.log(xx1);

$(xx1).text("Test 123")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="xx1"></div>
```

Comment: Man, I have been staring at this code too long. Thanks - that's the silliest error I have made in awhile. I'll accept this answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(idIndex[2]).text("text");`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code :

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){       
      var idIndex = ["xx1", "xx2", "xx3", "xx4"];
      $("#" + idIndex[2]).text("New text here");
     });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="xx1"></div>

    <div id="xx2"></div>

    <div id="xx3"></div>

    <div id="xx4"></div>
```